# Manage app lifecycle and hibernate state

Tags: c#, hibernate, event-handling, windows-8.1

I implemented according http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx an c# OnSuspend function. It works fine in case of suspending simulation via Visual Studio, but in real usage hibernate and standby will not be detected. Windows 8 System Trigger http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtrigger.aspx has also no power down events.

How can I detect standby and hibernate with Windows 8 c# apps?

Comment: I figured out, it is important to test without a debugger. I generated a new Split App project. The generated program files App.xaml.cs contains the OnSuspend function and calls SuspensionManager.SaveAsync(). In SaveAsync I added the following lines to trace every call of this function:               

file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("counter.txt",CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, t.ToLocalTime().ToString()+"\n");

Comment: I switched between App and desktop and also between running app and hibernate and running app and standby several times.

Comment: My trace results:
Sometimes every switch between app and desktop or app and metro view generates an event, but sometimes no event was thrown - I couldn't realy find a rule.
Starting hibernate seems to generate every time an event, but sometimes the event is to late and arises when the app awakes - this behavior was not expected
I tested a lot of times "starting the standby". Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes the events are also to late or lack.

Comment: Conclusion: The OnSuspend Event is the right event to detect hibernate and standby (and app suspend), but is unreliable to detect every event in time.